# Finding parametric equations for curve of intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

I am having difficulty finding parametric equations of the curve of intersection of $z = x^2 - y^2$ and cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

I am aware that the first equation represents a hyperboloid, and the second equation represents a cylinder. I think for the second one I can just do $x = cos(t)$ and $y = sin(t)$. Not sure about the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, the second equation implies that $x = \cos(t)$ and $y = \sin(t)$. Substituting these into the first equation yields
$$
z = x^2 - y^2 = \cos^2(t) - \sin^2(t) \, .
$$
Thus the curve is parametrized by
$$
(x(t), y(t), z(t)) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), \cos^2(t) - \sin^2(t)) = (\cos(t), \sin(t), \cos(2t)) \, .
$$

[Here's a SageMathCell illustrating the surfaces and curve of intersection](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtj8EKgzAQRO-F_sPixagr1JUe8ysWiaENVROSpahf36QieOhpZ5eZx-yn9yJfcMUNOS-uF9eABDdabgexdAQ1rB0hiAVrQiqiWneVvBS9ZnKjUYYfp1CVQiAlNP-SUW2HUna0PlKyp9d6zhK0TQV630-avVEHVigbBMdEMPNvpp1KLhKO8YZUOnMGej1kCPwy6j3rEOLpvr9XgUsNXfsF8F9Deg==&lang=sage), which produces the following plot.

$\hspace 4cm$ [image]

Comment: is that the intersection curve ? don't we need to equate to find that?

Comment: Yes, that's the curve of intersection. We substituted the parametrization obtained from the first equation into the second equation, so the result lies on the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

We have the two surfaces

$$
x^2-y^2 = z\\
x^2+y^2 = 1
$$

Solving for $x^2, y^2$ we have

$$
x^2 = \frac 12(1+z)\\
y^2 = \frac 12(1-z)
$$

so a parametric representation can be read as

$$
(x(s),y(s),z(s)) = \left(\pm\sqrt{\frac 12(1+s)},\pm\sqrt{\frac 12(1-s)},s\right)
$$

for $-1\le s \le 1$

Attached a plot with the four leafs

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For the first one use that $$\cosh^2(t)-\sinh^2(t)=1$$
And since$$x^2=z+y^2$$ we get

$$z+2y^2=1$$ so....
$$z=1-2y^2$$

Comment: Thanks so much. How can I find the parametric equation of the curve of intersection of these two? can I just equate?

Comment: so $z = 1 - 2\sin^2(t)$, right? I parametrized with $y = \sin(t)$

Comment: so $z = 1 - 2\sin^2(t)$, right? I parametrized with $y = \sin(t)$

Comment: i think this is ok so

Comment: wait so $1 - 2\sin^{2}(t)$ is the parametric equation of the curve of intersection for $z = x^2 - y^2$ and $1 = x^2 + y^2$